# Adding a permanent search title in autocomplete textview android

Tags: android, default, custom-component, autocompletetextview

I want to add a permanent search result in autocomplete text view in android. 
For ex:If i enter 'x' in the autocomplete and if it  shows the list of hotels...xyz1,xyz2.etc...Then the last result must be "NOT IN LIST" value. If the user cant find their hotel then they can select NOT IN LIST option..

Even if the user types in the text that the predictive search could not give then 'NOT IN LIST' should be the only suggestion that autocomplete should give. I am new to Android.I am doing a small app.Plz help..If i have to use custom autocomplete text view then what method should i override? If so ,tell me with a method code that i have to override

Comment: What kind of adapter do you use for the `AutoCompleteTextView`?

Comment: I use arrayadapter..which is populated from local json file
local json(parse)-->String array-->arrayadapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an `AutoCompleteAdapter` i used in one of my apps. I hope this solves you problem

Set the adapter from below to your `AutoCompleteTextView` control:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter(this,
            R.layout.dropdown_item);

    autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Sample adapter:

```
private class AutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
        implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList<String> mData;

    public AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        try {
            return mData.size();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return mData.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    //This shows a progress to the user in my app. you don't need to use this
                    handle.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_SHOW_PROGRESS);
                    try {
                        //Fill mData with your data
                        mData = XmlParser.searchLocations(constraint
                                .toString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        handle.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_HIDE_PROGRESS);
                    }
                    mData.add("NOT IN LIST");
                    filterResults.values = mData;
                    filterResults.count = mData.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint,
                    FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    handle.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_HIDE_PROGRESS);
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    handle.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_HIDE_PROGRESS);
                }
            }
        };
        return myFilter;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1879614 the code posted above will always add "NOT IN LIST" to the search result, isn't that what you've asked for?

Comment: u know that i am new to android. i tried for last one hour or so and got it...Sorry:( for being an idiot.  Thanks a lot..

Comment: I am trying to add an ArrayList<String> in to mdata. The autocomplete stopped working and it shows all the predicitive searches for any character input. What to do?

Comment: Check if you're filtering the results. Don't add all of your filterable data to mData, iterate through it and find the ones that match the user's query and add only those strings to mData.

Comment: if (constraint != null) {

    try {
        for(int i=0;i<temp.size();i++)
        {
        if(temp.get(i).toString().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
        {

        mData.add(temp.get(i).toString());  

        }
        }


        mData.add("SEARCH NOT THERE");

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }


         filterResults.values = mData;
         filterResults.count = mData.size();




}
return filterResults;

Comment: I have done my filtering...still it shows all the results instead of whatever i type in it...:(

Comment: @user1879614 if `temp` is the list of filterable data then your code is ok. Only thing left to try is clearing `mData` before you begin adding new items in `performFiltering(CharSequence)`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (constraint != null) {

    try {
        for(int i=0;i<temp.size();i++)
        {
        if(temp.get(i).toString().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
        {

        mData.add(temp.get(i).toString());  

        }
        }


        mData.add("SEARCH NOT THERE");

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }


         filterResults.values = mData;
         filterResults.count = mData.size();




}
return filterResults;
```

I have done my filtering...still it shows all the results instead of whatever i type in it...:(

Comment: you should edit your question instead of posting another question in the answers section. And don't forget to include edit summary when editing a question